# Explain this XML entity notation and reference

Tags: xml, dtd

Given the following XML file, what do the `DOCTYPE`, `ENTITY`, `SYSTEM`, `&entity` (reference?) represent?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
        <!ENTITY entity SYSTEM "./entity.xml">
]>

<root>
    <element attribute="value">
        &entity; 
        <child>
           <!-- some more nested -->
        </child>
    </element>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOCTYPE declaration is specifying the root element (`root`).

The entity declaration (`ENTITY`) is pointing to the file `entity.xml` on the system (`SYSTEM`).

The entity reference (`&entity;`) references the entity declaration named `entity`. The easiest way to think of it is that `&entity;` is replaced with everything that is in `entity.xml`.

Here's a good link that covers entities (including parameter entities): http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#sec-entity-decl

Answer (score 2):

It is the schema of the XML, in [DTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition) format.

Answer (score 2):

It is the format in which the XML is written. This is specifically written in DTD format. 
For more information I suggest [this](http://www.ldodds.com/delta/dtd_guide.html) guide that quickly explains how to read and understand said DTD format.

Also for more information about entities specifically, try [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_entities.asp) as well.

Comment: Good link, but it doesn't cover entity declarations.